# Generating an vector with rep and seq but without the c() function

Tags: r, sequence, rep

Suppose that I am not allowed to use the `c()` function.

My target is to generate the vector

"1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9"

Here is my attempt:

```
rep(seq(1, 5, 1), 5)

# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5

rep(0:4,rep(5,5))

# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

So basically I am sum them up. But I wonder if there is a better way to use rep and seq functions ONLY.

Comment: Why can't you use `c()`? It is an odd constraint and I'm not sure it makes sense. Everything in R is a vector so you can't prohibit the use of functions which create vectors. So can you do `1:3`? Or `rbind(1,2,3)  |> as.integer()`? I don't understand the rules of this really.

Comment: Sorry, but it is the question setting constraint to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```r
1:5 + rep(0:4, each = 5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

I like the `sequence` option as well:

```r
sequence(rep(5, 5), 1:5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
rep(1:5, each=5) + rep.int(0:4, 5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Just to be precise and use `seq` as well:

```
rep(seq.int(1:5), each=5) + rep.int(0:4, 5)
```

(PS: You can remove the `.int`s, but it's slower.)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
as.vector(sapply(1:5, `+`, 0:4))

[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also propose the `outer()` function as well:

```
library(dplyr) 
outer(1:5, 0:4, "+") %>%
array()
```

Or without magrittr `%>%` function in newer R versions:

```
outer(1:5, 0:4, "+") |>
    array()
```

Explanation.

The first function will create an array of 1:5 by 0:4 sequencies and fill the intersections with sums of these values:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6
[3,]    3    4    5    6    7
[4,]    4    5    6    7    8
[5,]    5    6    7    8    9
```

The second will pull the vector from the array and return the required vector:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```